# Logging for two different environment logs in to a single log file

Tags: spring, logging, jboss, log4j2

I am quite new for log4j2 logger and my requirement to write a log from application server and web server.

I am having two different environment on which J BOSS server is deployed.

Now I am having a log file on web server environment which is writing logs for errors and I want to write logs from application server also in same file.

Please suggest.

Comment: what have you done so far (code)?

Comment: i am able to write logs in a single file using log4j2. but only from current environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logs to be integrated together you should use a solution like Splunk or Elastic Search/Logstash/Kibana (ELK).

When you try to write to a file from 2 different processes your file will get corrupted unless you use file locking. However, your throughput will decrease significantly and it isn't supported for rolling files. So the best approach is to send the logs to a single process where they can be aggregated.